# How to suppress output of command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

For example:

```
cat a.txt
1 2
1 6    

{ cat $HOME/SANITY/file.txt | grep 1 >> $HOME/SANITY/new.txt } > /dev/null

cut -d' ' -f2
```

Now i don't want the results to be shown when running the script with this code.

Comment: Use `grep -q 1`.

Comment: You don't want the results of which command? You can redirect any command's stderr or stdout to `/dev/null` to get rid of it.

Comment: Use `awk` instead of this `grep`/`cut` combination.

Comment: The output of `cat` goes to `grep`, and the output of `grep` goes to `new.txt`. What results are you seeing go to the terminal instead?

Comment: @chepner - i am seeing same output on screen which is written in new.txt

Comment: @JNevill - If you see i tried that and still that shows output on screen

Comment: @iamauser - Let me try grep -q

Comment: A [mcve] that shows the specific unwanted output going to the screen would be helpful. You aren't showing *anything* being emitted by the 2nd line (the one with the `> /dev/null`), so it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can redirect the output. if you only use `your_command > /dev/null` only `stdout` will be redirected. If you want to remove the output of `stderr` as well, redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` using:

```
your_command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

`2>&1` will move `stderr` to the file descriptor of `stdout`.

Comment: `command` is the name of an actual built-in command that's part of the shell -- not necessarily ideal as a placeholder name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use in your case :

```
grep 1 "$HOME/SANITY/file.txt" >> "$HOME/SANITY/new.txt"
```

And for general purpose :

```
command_foo_bar > /dev/null # or any other non special file
```

Comment: You can try same by putting in .sh file and run. This command will give output on the screen.

Comment: @AnkurVerma It won't show any matching lines, but it will show potential errors like if the file can't be found